# PHP HttpRequest::setHeaders() converting my header names to camel case

Tags: php, http-headers, header, httprequest

I need to send the following header with my httpRequest:

'X-ABC-Reco-Token'=>'a0d15977';

I have the following code:

```
            $array = array("X-ABC-Reco-Token"=>$token);
            $this->request->setHeaders($array);
            echo var_dump($this->request->getHeaders());
```

however, this is the output I get:

```
 "X-Abc-Reco-Token"=>string 'a0d15977'
```

Note that PHP converted X-ABC to X-Abc.

Is there a way I can force the header to be the case I want?

Comment: Does the same happen calling `header()` with a string directly?

Comment: This would irritate me, too. But if you're checking http header names case-sensitively, you probably shouldn't, since the rfcs for both http 1.0 and 1.1 specifically state that http header names are case-insensitive.

Comment: Yeah, it's not me. The service that I'm calling is checking the headers case sensitively.

Comment: We discussed the issue, and the service providers agreed to change its code to check headers case insensitively. Anyways, it was an unnecessary delay on the project :(

Answer (score 0):

In worst case, you can make own class and inherit from httpRequest, then overload setHeaders function and make it work as you want. But you will need source code of that class to do this.

Other method in my mind is inherit from httpRequest and add a method like "fix()", which would set property of class where http request is waiting (maybe "queryData" ? - see http://www.php.net/manual/pl/class.httprequest.php) in your way by str_replace() Abc to ABC.